# Stroustrup's "Simple_window" shrinks when pushing "Next" button

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fltk

I have this piece of code based on Stroustrup's **Programming, Principles and practices using C++** book.

```
Point p(20, 100);                            // instance point where to fix the window
Simple_window win(p, 100, 100, "Canvas");    // instance a simple_window 100x100 pixel

while(true)
{           
    win.wait_for_button();                   // show the window in your screen until
                                             // you hit the "Next" button of the
                                             // window
}
```

What it does is just to instance a "Simple_window" object with the specified properties (size, position, etc) and draws whatever object you decide to attach to the window.

The window incorporates a "Next" button that, when pressed, redraws whatever has been attached later.

The problem is that, even without attaching anything to the window, succesive pressing of the "Next" button makes the window smaller. I debugged the FLTK library (fltk-1.3.2 for Windows) and only could find a function called

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

in Fl_win32.cxx file that seems to be responsible of that windows resizing, but I could not get anything else.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is probably more of a problem with the library than with FLTK.  Buttons in FLTK do not change in size, however many times you hit them.  Where did you get the library from?  Did it come precompiled or did you build it from source?

Comment: I downloaded the code from Stroustrup's book support webpage stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code and built it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This bug](http://www.fltk.org/str.php?L3061+P0+S-1+C0+I0+E0+V1.3+Q3061) was fixed in FLTK 1.3.3, released on November 3, 2014. The problem, according to the bug report, was:

> The cause of this behavior has to do with the way Windows uses the Border Padding setting, and the fact that FLTK doesn't take that setting into account altogether. 
>   Windows 7 uses padding to draw the border of resizable windows, and doesn't use it for non-resizable windows EXCEPT if MajorSubsystemVersion is 6 in the PE header. This is true if the Windows Classic or Windows Basic themes are being used. If the Aero theme is used, then all windows respect the Border Padding setting without exception, but the behavior I described still happens for whatever reason.

More details in the [bug report](http://www.fltk.org/str.php?L3061+P0+S-1+C0+I0+E0+V1.3+Q3061).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is a known issue on Windows 7 builds only

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/fltkgeneral/shrink/fltkgeneral/BRdzwxXJGgs/1lOkF_j9CyQJ

I had the same issue migrating my project from mac to windows.

I ignored much of this and just used an ugly workaround: resizing (ie with `win->resize(x,y,w,h)`) whenever I call `win->show()`. Explicitly with x,y,w,h from either the last known position/size or default position that it was initialised with depending on the behaviour you want.

A better approach (but still a bodge) might be to subclass the window (and call it `mywin` for instance), add some member variables `x_temp`,`y_temp`,`w_temp`,`h_temp`. Then define hide and show functions like

```
mywin::hide(){
    x_temp=x();
    y_temp=y();
    w_temp=w();
    h_temp=h();
    Fl_Window::hide();
}

mywin::show(){
    Fl_Window::show();
    resize(x_temp,y_temp,w_temp,h_temp);
}
```

Sounds like simple_window is a subclass of Fl_Window so you can either modify simple_window yourself or just subclass simple_window.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of this issue and, yes, I am using Windows 7. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that commenting both call to `hide()` in `Simple_window::next()` and call to `show()` in `Simple_window::wait_for_button()` avoid the window becoming smaller when clicking "Next" button.

Really don't know why or how, but it solved the window shrinking. I guess the whole winodw shrinking is an issue that happens in some "versions" of this GUI library, depending on from where and when you download it.

Thanks all for your help.